# NServiceBus: Handle Messages on demand

Tags: .net, nservicebus, servicebus, ondemand

I am just new to service busses (in particular NServiceBus) and have just written my first Saga.

The saga is intended to recieve a transaction and then send messages off to validate the users id, payment details, and product details, etc. against a mostly closed system (difficult to access programatically). now some of the functionality is easy to automate and write handlers for, but there are a few cases where manual intervention is required to complete the transaction as there is no api available to perform these tasks. Now we are going to have multiple human agents working against this so concurrency is an issue, and I thought why not have each user pull the next message on demand, and so utilise the concurrency inherent in MSMQ.

I haven't been able to find any methods on the IBus on nhibernate to allow for retrieving the next available message on demand as it appears everything is push based. So I have prototyped a a UI that manually retrieves the messages from MSMQ using the standard .NET System.Messaging.MessageQueue API and allows the user to interact with this and then send the return back to the saga by writing the response back via the IBus.Send() method.

My main question in regards to this is: Does this break the fundemental principles around NServiceBus? and if not is there anyway to do this through the NServiceBus API?

Also would you handle the concurrency through the MSMQ or through the UI application?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything in NSB is unidirectional on purpose for a [whole host of reasons](http://nservicebus.com/ArchitecturalPrinciples.aspx).  In order to notify your clients that they need to do something you could poll a view model to see if there is work to be done on some interval.  The Saga would be responsible for inserting/updating the right rows for the UI to pick up on.  Once the UI is complete you can use NSB to Send() a message back to the Saga.  If this is a web UI, check out the AsyncPages sample in the download.

Another way to do this would be to push a message to the client, assuming that messaging is installed along with the client.  You will need to create some kind of message pump in the background.  Again, once work is complete, a simple Send() will do.